# retrieve a field from sql through login

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've created 2 tables in a database, each table has a CompanyID field that's in relationship with eachother

In my registration page the company has to register the following info:

1. CompanyID
2. Company Name
3. Business Type
4. Contact Person
5. Telephone
6. Address
7. e-mail
8. Password

The company then logs in using their Company Name and Password, once logged in a company can post a job and the problem I have is in my jobtable there is also a field called CompanyID

How can I retrieve the CompanyID from the already registered companys stored in my Company table and use it

```
        SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("CompanyID", 'here' );
```

my full code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strcon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VC_temps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Store-Jobs", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("Job", TextBox1.Text);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("JobType", DropDownList1.Text);
    SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("StartDate", TextBox3.Text);
    SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("Time", TextBox2.Text);
    SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("JobID", TextBox1.Text.Substring(3).ToUpper());
    SqlParameter p6 = new SqlParameter("CompanyID", );
    SqlParameter p7 = new SqlParameter("PositionFilled", "NO");
    SqlParameter p8 = new SqlParameter("Description", TextBox4.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add(p1);
    com.Parameters.Add(p2);
    com.Parameters.Add(p3);
    com.Parameters.Add(p4);
    com.Parameters.Add(p5);
    com.Parameters.Add(p6);
    com.Parameters.Add(p7);
    com.Parameters.Add(p8);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Labelinfo.Text = "Post successful.";
}
```

Comment: Somewhere you must have session information of logged-in company . You can query company table for company id using company name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Since the user is logging in to a specific company then I am assuming the CompanyId would be the same during the entire session.  Therefore I would recommend retrieving the CompanyId during the login process and storing it into the Session variable.  Then you get the CompanyId from this session variable anytime you wish.

An alternative would be to pass the company name into the stored procedure and let the stored procedure get the CompanyId using the Company Name value.

On a secondary note....I like to show best practices when I see code that could have problems.  Your code will work fine if everything succeeds but if exceptions occur then you will leave SQL connections open.  I have taken the liberty to refactor your code to show an alternative...

```
string strcon = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VC_temps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"; 

// Use "using" statement to guarantee connection is closed even if exception occurs
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
{
    con.Open(); 
    using (SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand("Store-Jobs"))
    {
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Job", TextBox1.Text); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobType", DropDownList1.Text); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("StartDate", TextBox3.Text); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", TextBox2.Text); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobID", TextBox1.Text.Substring(3).ToUpper()); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CompanyID", ); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("PositionFilled", "NO"); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", TextBox4.Text); 
        com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
Labelinfo.Text = "Post successful.";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can use the company name to retrieve the company id from the Company table, using a different stored procedure, and then call the `Store-Job` procedure as you do in your code.
2. You can modify `Store-Job` to take the company name rather than the company id, and, within that procedure, look up the company id by company name and then use it for performing an Insert on teh Jobs table.
3. Since you have some form of verification going on at login, that might be a good time to retrieve the company id and store it in session (as Gene S suggests above).  You can then retrieve it and use it in your stored procedure.

Since you will probably need to use it in many places in your app, to ensure that the data being saved or retrieved belongs to the right company, option 3 sounds like the best.